# Change the saturation of a QPixmap with pyside/pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, maya, pixmap

I would like to make a Subclass of QLabel that acts as a boolean toggle button. I would like to be able to assign any pixmap, and have the image be desaturated when the button state is False.
I am guessing this could be done with QColor somehow, but am not really sure how I would implement this.
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do what you want using [QGraphicsColorizeEffect](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicscolorizeeffect.html):

```
    self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
    effect = QtGui.QGraphicsColorizeEffect(self.label)
    effect.setStrength(0.0)
    effect.setColor(QtGui.QColor('silver'))
    self.label.setGraphicsEffect(effect)
```

To toggle the effect, [set the strength](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicscolorizeeffect.html#strength-prop) as appropriate:

```
    if self.label.graphicsEffect().strength():
        self.label.graphicsEffect().setStrength(0.0)
    else:
        self.label.graphicsEffect().setStrength(0.5)
```